# Is copying /bin from bootable usb safe?

Tags: boot, 16.10

30 mins ago I was trying to add a symbolic link in opt of a dir named bin, when I realized something wasn't right I deleted it, but then I had problems. I turned off the pc and when I restarted it I couldn't boot into ubuntu. Turns out that instead of deleting that bin symbolic link I deleted /bin. I booted from a live usb and I copied it's /bin into my broken installation. Now it works but when I turn the pc on I see three or four white text lines and it takes some seconds more then usual. While writing this Ubuntu also told me about an internal error of gnome-terminal. What do I do? Can I consider this fixed or should I reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh install would be a clean solution to this problem.

If that is a lot of work, another idea is to use VirtualBox or Qemu/kvm to do a fresh install in a Virtual Machine, and then install the same applications that have been used on your current install. After you have that, you could make a copy of /bin from the VM, and copy that across.

Comment: In the end I simply went with the option to reinstall the system but keep my files.